# omz_urlencode:42: -regex-match not available for regex

Tags: regex, terminal, homebrew, symlink, zshrc

Okay so i'm trying to install Homebrew, so that I can I can install nodejs and npm. However I'm using this command from brew.sh;

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Once I install Homebrew It keeps returning this error

> It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
>   should do the following before running this installer again:
>       `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`
>   The current contents of /usr/local are bin CODEOFCONDUCT.md etc lib libexec Library LICENSE.txt README.md sbin share .git .github .gitignore
>   omz_urlencode:42: failed to load module `zsh/regex': dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.2/lib/zsh/regex.so, 9): image not found
>   omz_urlencode:42: -regex-match not available for regex'

I honestly have no idea what's happening here. I'm not sure If I have to symlink Homebrew up or what. But I have tried everything I know so far (which isn't much). If anyone could be kind enough to give me instructions as what too look for to solve the issue, I'm all ears.

Thank you for listening!

Comment: On another note whenever I type in a command on the CLI it also returns no matter what I type: env: node: No such file or directory
omz_urlencode:42: failed to load module `zsh/regex': dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.2/lib/zsh/regex.so, 9): image not found                              
omz_urlencode:42: -regex-match not available for regex

Comment: You did install Oh My ZSH, didn't you?

Comment: Hi Thomas, yes I'm using oh my zsh.

Comment: The first [update it](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh#getting-updates)

Comment: Hey Thomas, so I've updated the oh my zsh, seems to have done that fine. I have homebrew installed, but whenever Im running the command 'homebrew -v' it returns 'zsh: command not found: homebrew' i've tried to run 'brew install node' and that returns 'Warning: node-5.10.1 already installed, it's just not linked' so im assuming that I have a node module in my cellar and have to symlink it up? but I'm not too sure on how to do it. Thanks for the help I really appreciate it.

Comment: So i've tried using the command 'brew link node'; brew link node 
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/5.10.1... 
Error: Could not symlink share/doc/node/gdbinit
Target /usr/local/share/doc/node/gdbinit
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/share/doc/node/gdbinit'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's a bug that have been corrected in recent version of OMZ, you should [update it](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh#getting-updates).

You get the output:

> zsh: command not found: homebrew

Because `homebrew` is not a command. Try `brew -v` instead.

To resolve:

> Warning: node-5.10.1 already installed, it's just not linked

Use `brew link node`

Comment: Hey Thomas, thank you for the reply, I've tried brew -v and that seems to be  fine, thanks for that. but when im typing the command 'brew link node' it returns: 'Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/5.10.1... 
Error: Could not symlink share/doc/node/gdbinit
Target /usr/local/share/doc/node/gdbinit
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/share/doc/node/gdbinit'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node'

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I think I have made some progress, It may have been for some weird reason I didn't have permission writes to run the 'brew link < package > ' so i ran the following command:

'sudo chown -R /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset && brew doctor'

Once I ran 'brew link node' it successfully created 7 symlinks for the node directory on the following path;

'Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/5.10.1... 7 symlinks created'

However, when I installed live-server via npm; I typed 'live-server -v' and it again returned 'zsh: command not found: live-server'. In addition to this it keeps telling me I have 'unbrewed dylibs':

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libociei.dylib

So im still unsure what the exact issue is.

P.S. Apologies for not posting this correctly, as im trying to see where I can seperate it into commands like you corrected in the first post, if you could link me to a post where it tells me how to use it properly i'll be more than happy to read it.

Thanks,